# Where are the swap files stored?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-space, virtual-memory

The swap files used to be stored at /var/vm but when I look there on Catalina, the only thing I find is a sleepimage of approximately 1 GB. Where is the swap stored? Want to know how much of the disk it consumes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this thread: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252816786

> They likely changed that with Big Sur. I think it was mounted to /private/var/vm/ in Catalina. Mounting it to /System/Volumes parallels the rest of the volumes in Big Sur.

> The swapfile (swapfile0) appears to be at /System/Volumes/VM now

Comment: /private/var/vm was always the directory /var is a link to /private/var since NeXT